# Does chrome the host env instantiate the Global Objects such as Object, Function, using global constructors

Tags: javascript, constructor, javascript-objects, v8

I am curious as to why and how does chrome, (the host env) instantiate the Global Objects such as `Object`, `Function`.

Is it using the global `Function()`, `Object()` constructors and why does it provide the constructors (Function(), Object()) and the global objects (Objects, Function) both in the environment on the window object.

Is it because providing both (global functions and constructor) is necessary for the environment to create functions and objects defined in the user script or the global constructors are redundant (since they already instantiated their own global objects, namely Object, Function)

I'm sorry if this sounds stupid but I really don't get the function object concept and may be way of how the browser implements can shed light at the end of the tunnel.

Thanks.

Comment: Well obviously it cannot use `new Function` to create the global `Function` object?

Comment: "*the constructors (Function(), Object()) and the global objects (Objects, Function)*" - not sure what you think the difference is between those? There is only one `Object` and one `Function`.

Comment: related: [Function and Object Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12881552/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Thank you so much for sharing this. Clears the air. Just to be sure this line from your answer to that question: `function somewhere in the code of EcmaScript environment ` implies any Global function objects such as `Function`, `Object`, `String` are outputs of the that source c++ function (in context of v8) ?



Again, thumbs up for being very simple, concise and clear answer to the above linked question.

Comment: Yes, the main builtin objects are created and initialised by the v8 C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, functions are objects. Don't let yourself be confused by their names, both `Object` and `Function` are functions (and, like all functions, they are objects too). Consider the following example with different names:

```
function my_func() { return 42; }
my_func.property = "hello";    // Functions can have properties.
var my_var = my_func;          // You can store functions in variables.
console.log(typeof my_var);    // "function"
console.log(my_func());        // 42
console.log(my_var());         // 42
console.log(my_var.property);  // "hello"
```

Instead of "function my_func() {...}" I could have written "function Object() {...}". (Except, of course, that would clash weirdly with the built-in `Object` function.)

Like all functions, `Object` is not constructed with itself. Invoking `new Object()` gives you an empty object (just like writing `{}` would), which is not the same as the `Object` function. The definition of these functions is built into the JavaScript engine; they are instantiated at startup using special built-in code that is not exposed to JavaScript.

In my example above, observe how `... = my_func` refers to the function, and `... = my_func()` calls it. In the same way, `Object()` really is a two-part expression (`Object` + `()`) that refers to the `Object` function and calls it. So it's logically impossible to use `Object()` to create `Object`, because that would require using something that doesn't exist yet! In other words, providing "both" `Object` and `Object()` is the same thing: `Object` is provided, and since it's a function you can call it with `()`.

Maybe another example will help. In typical JavaScript code, you have user-defined constructor functions like:

```
function Fruit(color) {
  this.color = color;
}
Fruit.shape = "curved";

var banana = new Fruit("yellow");
console.log(typeof Fruit);   // "function"
console.log(typeof banana);  // "object"
console.log(banana.shape);   // undefined
console.log(banana.constructor.shape);      // "curved"
console.log(banana === Fruit);              // false
console.log(banana.constructor === Fruit);  // true
```

Observe how invoking `new Fruit()` as a constructor does not give you the `Fruit` function (just like invoking `new Object()` does not give you the `Object` function). You can put properties on `Fruit` (which, being a function, is also an object), and accessing them works just like accessing any other object property.